# How to pass a function with it's object reference to another function to execute

Tags: c#, delegates, action, func

I suppose this is a fairly simple thing that I am trying to do but I am probably missing something here.

Say I have a few functions that all do *ALMOST* the same thing except for one line, this definitely calls for a "base" function or something along those lines, where that *ONE* different line would be passed over to it and executed, and the rest of the code will continue it's flow.

Here's my example:

Let's say I have a few functions that perform operation on a `Car` object and validate that the operation is successful:

```
public void SoundHorn()
{
            var response = _car.Horn(1000);
            if(response.Status != 0)
            {
                throw new Exception("Operation failed!");
            }
}

public void TurnOnHazardLights()
{
            var response = _car.ToggleHazards(true);
            if(response.Status != 0)
            {
                throw new Exception("Operation failed!");
            }
}
```

As you can see the only difference is the actual functionto perform, the validation is the same for all of them.

What I ultimately would want is to have a "base" function along those lines:

```
private void PerformOperation(??? operation)
{
            var response = operation.Invoke();
            if(response.Status != 0)
            {
                throw new Exception("Operation failed!");
            }
}
```

And so the other functions would look like:

```
public void TurnOnHazarLights()
    {
                PerformOperation(_car.togglehazards);
    }
```

I am aware of Delegates, Actions and Func, and it seems that they require me to pass over the Function to run itself, without it's object reference, and this I unable to use the above syntax.

I suppose I am missing the usage of one of these above mentioned classes.

Could you please enlighten me on this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Delegates are indeed what you need. In this case, since the operations all operate on a `Car`   object and returns something, you need an `Func<Car, Something>`, where `Something` is the type that `Horn` and others return:

```
private void PerformOperation(Func<Car, Something> operation)
{
        var response = operation.Invoke(_car);
        if(response.Status != 0)
        {
            throw new Exception("Operation failed!");
        }
}
```

And you can write the two specialised operations like this:

```
public void SoundHorn()
{
    PerformOperation(car => car.Horn(1000));
}

public void TurnOnHazardLights()
{
    PerformOperation(car => car.ToggleHazards(true));
}
```

Comment: `Action<Car>` has no return value. In that example you would need to define the parameter as `Func<Car, int>` to check for the result.

Comment: @PeterWurzinger oops! I didn’t notice that! But the return value doesn’t seem to be `int` though, seeing how there is a `Status` property.

Comment: @Sweeper Thanks a lot for the concise explanation here!

Answer (score 1):

This would be

```
 private void PerformOperation(Func<int> operation)
```

And you Define

```
 public void TurnOnHazarLights() => PerformOperation(()=>_car.ToggleHazards(true));
 public void SoundHorn() => PerformOperation(() => m_car.SoundHorn(100))
```

Or replace < int > with the type of your Response class.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm overseeing something, but why wouldn't that work:

```cs
private void PerformOperation(Func<Response> operation)
{
            var response = operation();
            if(response.Status != 0)
            {
                throw new Exception("Operation failed!");
            }
}
```

You would then call it via

```cs
PerformOperation(() => _car.ToggleHazards(true));
```

Comment: Thanks! Indeed as I expected, this seems to be what I was looking for!
Just a clarification, what would be the difference here if I used operation.Invoke() rather than just operation() as you have suggested?

Comment: Just syntactic sugar in this case - pick that version which looks better to you.